# Resize text/div using mouse in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, size

I'm looking to create a very simple way to allow users to be able to resize text. I want a box around a word or paragraph with handles that will allow the user to resize the box. Then the text inside the box auto resize to fit the new box.

How can I create the handles similar to the screen below?

The only example I can find is on VistaPrints web site.

Screenshot

[image]

Here is a [link](http://www.vistaprint.com/vp/ns/studio3.aspx?template=857333_B7K&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vistaprint.com%2Fgallery%2FIOUCAAABAAEAAAA%3D%2Fpersonal-business-cards.aspx%3Fxnav%3DProductHub_Carousel_1_BC1&ag=True&uei=704733&filter=9%3A10013%7C%7C1%2C3%3A10529%7C%7C1&xnav=previews&xnid=image_172&rd=1) to the page:

Comment: In what part exactly you got stuck? HTML, CSS, JavaScript... How far you got with your attempt? Show us your code and you will get help

Comment: What stops you from opening Inspector in your browser and looking how it's actually made on the page you're showing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with using jquery's resizable ui http://jqueryui.com/resizable/.

If you want to have the text auto sized to fit the container then use slabText http://freqdec.github.io/slabText/

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for something "simple", then I would try jQuery UI.  It offers both [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) and [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) widgets.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/7fwgsk2m/)

Here's a sample of how you can combine the two and use some custom CSS to get the behavior you want.  Adding `contenteditable="true"` will allow users to edit the contents as well, but you'll need some additional javascript to remove the 'draggable' while editing.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='resizable draggable'>
    <h1 contenteditable="true">Resize Me</h1>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.draggable {
    cursor: move;
}
.resizable {
    border: 1px dashed #000000;
    position: relative;
}
.ui-resizable-nw, .ui-resizable-ne, .ui-resizable-sw, .ui-resizable-se, .ui-resizable-n, .ui-resizable-e, .ui-resizable-s, .ui-resizable-w {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: absolute;
}
.ui-resizable-nw {
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    cursor: nw-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-ne {
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    cursor: ne-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-sw {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: sw-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-se {
    bottom: -5px;
    right:-5px;
    cursor: se-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-n {
    top: -5px;
    left:50%;
    cursor: n-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-s {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: s-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-w {
    left:-5px;
    top:calc(50% - 5px);
    cursor: w-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-e {
    right:-5px;
    top:calc(50% - 5px);
    cursor: e-resize;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.resizable').resizable({
    handles: {
        'nw': '.ui-resizable-nw',
        'ne': '.ui-resizable-ne',
        'sw': '.ui-resizable-sw',
        'se': '.ui-resizable-se',
        'n': '.ui-resizable-n',
        'e': '.ui-resizable-e',
        's': '.ui-resizable-s',
        'w': '.ui-resizable-w'
    }
});
$( '.draggable' ).draggable().on('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).is('.ui-draggable-dragging') ) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).draggable( 'option', 'disabled', true );
    $(this).prop('contenteditable','true');
})
.on('blur', function(){
    $(this).draggable( 'option', 'disabled', false);
    $(this).prop('contenteditable','false');
});
```

Comment: if you click at the end of the text (resize me) and start pressing delete it will delete the div's for the resize handlers.  Is there a way to stop that?

Answer (score 2):

I am giving you an algorithm:

Create a div and set a border (Big div) -> Place it using position: absolute;

Create 8 div (little square) -> Place them using position: absolute;

Use events [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/), [mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/?s=mouseup), [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) to the 8 div

- When the mouseenter is fired, set boolean var.
- When the mousedown is fired, if mouseenter is equals to true, set mousemove.
- When mousemove is fired, move your little div which is hovered. Dynamically change big div size and position of the 8 div.
- When mouseup is fired, disable mousemove.
- When mouseleave is fired, set boolean false.

Gl doing it, if you get any problem during the implementation, you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI would probably do it for you: 
http://jqueryui.com/resizable/